# Como hacer para que el texto aparezca en una nueva linea en una tabla

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy trabajando com mvc, pero al mostrar una tabla me aparece asi 
https://gyazo.com/31ced13cc743e7afd08d3132cd037522

Esta es mi view

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Methods.CurrentTable.GetColumns().Count(); i++)
    {

        <th>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(item => Methods.CurrentTable.GetColumns()[i].ColumnName)    
        </th>
     }
</tr>   
<tr> 
   @for (int i = 0; i < Methods.Rows.Count(); i++)
   {
       for (int m = 0; m < Methods.Rows[i].Registers.Count(); m++)
       {
           if (Methods.Rows[i].Registers[m] != "")
           {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => Methods.Rows[i].Registers[m])<br />

            </td>
           }
       }
   }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que colocar el `<tr>` dentro del primer for asi:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Methods.CurrentTable.GetColumns().Count(); i++)
    {

        <th>
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(item => Methods.CurrentTable.GetColumns()[i].ColumnName)    
        </th>
     }
</tr>   

   @for (int i = 0; i < Methods.Rows.Count(); i++)
   {
       <tr>
       for (int m = 0; m < Methods.Rows[i].Registers.Count(); m++)
       {
           if (Methods.Rows[i].Registers[m] != "")
           {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => Methods.Rows[i].Registers[m])<br />

            </td>
           }
       }
       </tr>
   }

</table>
```

Comment: No me habia dado cuenta, muchas gracias, perdon por la molestia.